# Sublime Text 3 - PHPcs plugin adding fullstops

Tags: git, sublimetext3, phpcs

I'm have an issue with my phpcs coding standards using Sublime Text 3.

**The issue outlined:**

I run phpcs automatically on save within each of my documents, and it's doing an amazing job. I have correct spaces and tabs, but my problem occurs when I am committing my work.

My commits are almost unreadable this is because my PSR2 coding standard is adding full-stops and commas to the end of lines. I have googled and can't find how to ignore parts of the coding standard.

**Example:**

[image: The figure showing my commit Diff with fullstops]

**Reason for this being a problem:**

As you can see in the above picture the green lines at the top of the picture are the automatically edited lines. The issue is everyone else's programs (Atom, Net Beans, Sublime Text 2) in the office using PSR2 coding standards do not add these fullstops (and commas) into their code, so my commits are really messy.

**The soultion:**

I would really like to clean up my commits and have the phpcs ignore these commas/full-stops, so my commits only include the code I have actually changed. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure the [PHP Coding Standards Fixer](http://cs.sensiolabs.org/) with rules appropriate for your project.

For example, the PHP Coding Standards Fixer has the rule `phpdoc_short_description` which if enabled means "PHPDoc short descriptions should end in either a full stop, exclamation mark, or question mark.". This why the full stops are being added to your PHPDoc descriptions.

If you wanted to use the default rules with just that particular rule disabled then you might create a `.php_cs` file in the root of your project with the following:

```
<?php

$finder = Symfony\CS\Finder\DefaultFinder::create()
    ->in(__DIR__)
;

return Symfony\CS\Config\Config::create()
    ->fixers(array('-phpdoc_short_description'))
    ->finder($finder)
;
```

See the [PHP Coding Standards Fixer](http://cs.sensiolabs.org/) site for complete list of the rules.

Some of the PHP Coding Standard Fixer rules:

```
'-psr0', // [PSR-0] Classes must be in a path that matches their namespace, be at least one namespace deep, and the class name should match the file name.
'-encoding', // [PSR-1] PHP code MUST use only UTF-8 without BOM (remove BOM).
'-short_tag', // [PSR-1] PHP code must use the long <?php ?\> tags or the short-echo <?= ?\> tags; it must not use the other tag variations.
'-braces', // [PSR-2] The body of each structure MUST be enclosed by braces. Braces should be properly placed. Body of braces should be properly indented.
'-elseif', // [PSR-2] The keyword elseif should be used instead of else if so that all control keywords looks like single words.
'-eof_ending', // [PSR-2] A file must always end with a single empty line feed.
'-function_call_space', // [PSR-2] When making a method or function call, there MUST NOT be a space between the method or function name and the opening parenthesis.
'-function_declaration', // [PSR-2] Spaces should be properly placed in a function declaration.
'-indentation', // [PSR-2] Code MUST use an indent of 4 spaces, and MUST NOT use tabs for indenting.
'-line_after_namespace', // [PSR-2] There MUST be one blank line after the namespace declaration.
'-linefeed', // [PSR-2] All PHP files must use the Unix LF (linefeed) line ending.
'-lowercase_constants', // [PSR-2] The PHP constants true, false, and null MUST be in lower case.
'-lowercase_keywords', // [PSR-2] PHP keywords MUST be in lower case.
'-method_argument_space', // [PSR-2] In method arguments and method call, there MUST NOT be a space before each comma and there MUST be one space after each comma.
'-multiple_use', // [PSR-2] There MUST be one use keyword per declaration.
'-parenthesis', // [PSR-2] There MUST NOT be a space after the opening parenthesis. There MUST NOT be a space before the closing parenthesis.
'-php_closing_tag', // [PSR-2] The closing ?\> tag MUST be omitted from files containing only PHP.
'-single_line_after_imports', // [PSR-2] Each namespace use MUST go on its own line and there MUST be one blank line after the use statements block.
'-trailing_spaces', // [PSR-2] Remove trailing whitespace at the end of non-blank lines.
'-visibility', // [PSR-2] Visibility MUST be declared on all properties and methods; abstract and final MUST be declared before the visibility; static MUST be declared after the visibility.
'-array_element_no_space_before_comma', // [symfony] In array declaration, there MUST NOT be a whitespace before each comma.
'-array_element_white_space_after_comma', // [symfony] In array declaration, there MUST be a whitespace after each comma.
'-blankline_after_open_tag', // [symfony] Ensure there is no code on the same line as the PHP open tag and it is followed by a blankline.
'-concat_without_spaces', // [symfony] Concatenation should be used without spaces.
'-double_arrow_multiline_whitespaces', // [symfony] Operator => should not be surrounded by multi-line whitespaces.
'-duplicate_semicolon', // [symfony] Remove duplicated semicolons.
'-empty_return', // [symfony] A return statement wishing to return nothing should be simply "return".
'-extra_empty_lines', // [symfony] Removes extra empty lines.
'-function_typehint_space', // [symfony] Add missing space between function's argument and its typehint.
'-include', // [symfony] Include and file path should be divided with a single space. File path should not be placed under brackets.
'-join_function', // [symfony] Implode function should be used instead of join function.
'-list_commas', // [symfony] Remove trailing commas in list function calls.
'-multiline_array_trailing_comma', // [symfony] PHP multi-line arrays should have a trailing comma.
'-namespace_no_leading_whitespace', // [symfony] The namespace declaration line shouldn't contain leading whitespace.
'-new_with_braces', // [symfony] All instances created with new keyword must be followed by braces.
'-no_blank_lines_after_class_opening', // [symfony] There should be no empty lines after class opening brace.
'-no_empty_lines_after_phpdocs', // [symfony] There should not be blank lines between docblock and the documented element.
'-object_operator', // [symfony] There should not be space before or after object T_OBJECT_OPERATOR.
'-operators_spaces', // [symfony] Binary operators should be surrounded by at least one space.
'-phpdoc_indent', // [symfony] Docblocks should have the same indentation as the documented subject.
'-phpdoc_inline_tag', // [symfony] Fix PHPDoc inline tags, make inheritdoc always inline.
'-phpdoc_no_access', // [symfony] access annotations should be omitted from phpdocs.
'-phpdoc_no_empty_return', // [symfony] return void and @return null annotations should be omitted from phpdocs.
'-phpdoc_no_package', // [symfony] package and @subpackage annotations should be omitted from phpdocs.
'-phpdoc_params', // [symfony] All items of the @param, @throws, @return, @var, and @type phpdoc tags must be aligned vertically.
'-phpdoc_scalar', // [symfony] Scalar types should always be written in the same form. "int", not "integer"; "bool", not "boolean"; "float", not "real" or "double".
'-phpdoc_separation', // [symfony] Annotations in phpdocs should be grouped together so that annotations of the same type immediately follow each other, and annotations of a different type are separated by a single blank line.
'-phpdoc_short_description', // [symfony] Phpdocs short descriptions should end in either a full stop, exclamation mark, or question mark.
'-phpdoc_to_comment', // [symfony] Docblocks should only be used on structural elements.
'-phpdoc_trim', // [symfony] Phpdocs should start and end with content, excluding the very first and last line of the docblocks.
'-phpdoc_type_to_var', // [symfony] type should always be written as @var.
'-phpdoc_types', // [symfony] The correct case must be used for standard PHP types in phpdoc.
'-phpdoc_var_without_name', // [symfony] var and @type annotations should not contain the variable name.
'-pre_increment', // [symfony] Pre incrementation/decrementation should be used if possible.
'-print_to_echo', // [symfony] Converts print language construct to echo if possible.
'-remove_leading_slash_use', // [symfony] Remove leading slashes in use clauses.
'-remove_lines_between_uses', // [symfony] Removes line breaks between use statements.
'-return', // [symfony] An empty line feed should precede a return statement.
'-self_accessor', // [symfony] Inside a classy element "self" should be preferred to the class name itself.
'-short_bool_cast', // [symfony] Short cast bool using double exclamation mark should not be used.
'-single_array_no_trailing_comma', // [symfony] PHP single-line arrays should not have trailing comma.
'-single_blank_line_before_namespace', // [symfony] There should be exactly one blank line before a namespace declaration.
'-single_quote', // [symfony] Convert double quotes to single quotes for simple strings.
'-spaces_before_semicolon', // [symfony] Single-line whitespace before closing semicolon are prohibited.
'-spaces_cast', // [symfony] A single space should be between cast and variable.
'-standardize_not_equal', // [symfony] Replace all <> with !=.
'-ternary_spaces', // [symfony] Standardize spaces around ternary operator.
'-trim_array_spaces', // [symfony] Arrays should be formatted like function/method arguments, without leading or trailing single line space.
'-unalign_double_arrow', // [symfony] Unalign double arrow symbols.
'-unalign_equals', // [symfony] Unalign equals symbols.
'-unary_operators_spaces', // [symfony] Unary operators should be placed adjacent to their operands.
'-unneeded_control_parentheses', // [symfony] Removes unneeded parentheses around control statements.
'-unused_use', // [symfony] Unused use statements must be removed.
'-whitespacy_lines', // [symfony] Remove trailing whitespace at the end of blank lines.
'-align_double_arrow', // [contrib] Align double arrow symbols in consecutive lines.
'-align_equals', // [contrib] Align equals symbols in consecutive lines.
'-concat_with_spaces', // [contrib] Concatenation should be used with at least one whitespace around.
'-echo_to_print', // [contrib] Converts echo language construct to print if possible.
'-ereg_to_preg', // [contrib] Replace deprecated ereg regular expression functions with preg. Warning! This could change code behavior.
'-header_comment', // [contrib] Add, replace or remove header comment.
'-logical_not_operators_with_spaces', // [contrib] Logical NOT operators (!) should have leading and trailing whitespaces.
'-logical_not_operators_with_successor_space', // [contrib] Logical NOT operators (!) should have one trailing whitespace.
'-long_array_syntax', // [contrib] Arrays should use the long syntax.
'-multiline_spaces_before_semicolon', // [contrib] Multi-line whitespace before closing semicolon are prohibited.
'-newline_after_open_tag', // [contrib] Ensure there is no code on the same line as the PHP open tag.
'-no_blank_lines_before_namespace', // [contrib] There should be no blank lines before a namespace declaration.
'-ordered_use', // [contrib] Ordering use statements.
'-php4_constructor', // [contrib] Convert PHP4-style constructors to __construct. Warning! This could change code behavior.
'-php_unit_construct', // [contrib] PHPUnit assertion method calls like "->assertSame(true, )" should be written with dedicated method like "->assertTrue()". Warning! This could change code behavior.
'-php_unit_strict', // [contrib] PHPUnit methods like "assertSame" should be used instead of "assertEquals". Warning! This could change code behavior.
'-phpdoc_order', // [contrib] Annotations in phpdocs should be ordered so that param annotations come first, then throws annotations, then return annotations.
'-phpdoc_var_to_type', // [contrib] var should always be written as @type.
'-short_array_syntax', // [contrib] PHP arrays should use the PHP 5.4 short-syntax.
'-short_echo_tag', // [contrib] Replace short-echo <?= with long format <?php echo syntax.
'-strict', // [contrib] Comparison should be strict. Warning! This could change code behavior.
'-strict_param' // [contrib] Functions should be used with  param. Warning! This could change code behavior.
```

Comment: Thanks bro! I think i am sorting it now :)